# Question about Cauchy sequences are convergent in $\mathbb{R}^k$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, cauchy-sequences

Let $\{p_n\}$ be a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}^k$.  Let $K = cl \{p_n\}$ be an infinite compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^k$ (so $K$ is the closure of the set that consists of all distinct elements  in the Cauchy sequence $\{p_n\}$). Let $p$ be a limit point of $K$.

1. If we know that the neighborhood of p of radius 1 $N_1(p) \cap cl\{p_n\}$ is infinite, how can we prove that $N_1(p)\cap\{p_n\}$ is infinite?
2. Is the set $\{p_n\}$ open or closed?

The proof of the first question is an intermediate step of the proof that Cauchy sequences are convergent in $\mathbb{R}^k$, but I don't know how to approach it.

For the second question, I think the set is open, cuase otherwise $\{p_n\} = cl\{p_n\}$ and the first question becomes trivial, but I'm not sure why it is open.

Comment: What is a cpt??

Comment: Clean up that nonsense so that k is not two different things at the same time.

Comment: What is N$_1$??

Comment: {p$_n$} is not an infinite set.  It is a set with exactly one point, namely  p$_n$.  Do you mean let K = { p$_n$ : n in N }  be a countable subset of R$^k$.

Comment: What does "Cauchy is convergent" mean?

Answer (score 0):

Let K be a countable subset of R$^n$.

Q1. If p is a limit point of K, U is an
open nhood of p, then U $\cap$ K is infinite.
If not, then an open nhood of p can be constructed that misses K except possibly at p.
So p is not a limit point of K.
If K is the set of points of Cauchy sequence s,   then K is finite iff s is eventually constant.

Q2.  K is not open because open subsets of
R$^k$ are uncountable.  K is closed iff it
contains all of it limit points.